# Windows doesn't switch audio inputs automatically

Tags: windows-10, audio, input-device, system-sounds

I upgraded my PC a while back and changed the motherboard. I have a pair of speaker connected from the back of my PC and they work fine. The problem is that when I connect my headphones, the system doesn't switch automatically to it. So I have to do it manually by going into playback devices settings and make it a default device, then changing it back after I'm done. It works fine on Ubuntu but not on Windows 10. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faced the same problem with windows 10, mostly it an audio driver issue. These are some things which I did as a temporary fix

1. Restart the PC (bonus frustration skype call and mic stopped
       working)
2. updated the audio drivers - mine is Realtek, no success.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it! I [downloaded](http://download.viatech.com/en/support/driversSelect.jsp) the VIA driver and installed it. There's a new version now. Then I disabled the input I didn't need because I noticed it switched automatically to my monitor which does not have a speaker. The audio input now switches automatically.